# React - Invariant Violation exception

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, react-dom

Being new to React am stuck with something that should seemingly be pretty straightforward. Not sure what am doing wrong.

I have a component **BasicReactComponent.js** like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const BasicReactComp = () => {
  console.log('hi');
  return (
    <div>
      I was loaded from basic react comp.
    </div>
  );
};

export default BasicReactComp;
```

Am trying to call it in my main file like below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
const BasicReactComp = require('./BasicReactComp');

ReactDOM.render(
 <BasicReactComp />,
 document.getElementById('foo')
);
```

I keep getting the below error

```
**Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
    Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.**
```

Comment: Use `import BasicReactComp from './BasicReactComp'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When translating between ES6 modules and CommonJS modules, default exports are exported as a `default` *property*. Hence you have to access `.default` of the value you `require`:

```
const BasicReactComp = require('./BasicReactComp').default;
```

Or use the `import` syntax:

```
import BasicReactComp from './BasicReactComp';
```

Comment: #FacePalm.... Thank you so much... That fixed it :)

Comment: @felix-king, do you happen to know if there is a way I could do something like this... $('#foo').append(ReactDOM.render(
          <BasicReactComp />,
          document.createElement('div')
        )); For some reason it isnt working...  The thing is I would want the component to be rendered inside a div which is appended to another element

Comment: Nevermind figured it :)